# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU failed to install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I'm going to use window 8, 32 bit, core i3
I have already installed visual studio 2010 in my PC.But after formatting my pc, when tried to reinstall it, it gives me error : Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU failed to install.Please help me to get out of this.

error log :

```
[09/17/14,21:02:42] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.
[09/17/14,21:02:42] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: d:\study\software\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs_setup.msi
[09/17/14,21:02:44] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU is not installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:44] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:44] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:45] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:02:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:04] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.
[09/17/14,21:17:04] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: d:\study\software\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs_setup.msi
[09/17/14,21:17:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU is not installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:17:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:10] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.
[09/17/14,21:56:11] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: d:\study\software\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs_setup.msi
[09/17/14,21:56:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU is not installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:16] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:16] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:16] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:16] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:16] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:16] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:17] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:17] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:17] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/17/14,21:56:17] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:51] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.
[09/22/14,11:39:51] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: d:\study\software\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs_setup.msi
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU is not installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:54] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:55] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,11:39:56] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:44] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.
[09/22/14,12:16:44] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: d:\study\software\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs_setup.msi
[09/22/14,12:16:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU is not installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:46] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:47] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:48] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:49] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:49] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:49] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:49] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:49] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:49] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:50] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/22/14,12:16:50] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x86 was not attempted to be installed.
```

Comment: What was the reason for "formatting my pc"?  A pretty drastic thing to do, but does not solve hardware problems.  The kind that causes a file to get corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all to help me.
Finally solved this, just follow this steps before try to install again.

1. Uninstall all visual studio 2010 setup from control panel.
2. clear temp folder (run -> %temp%)
3. Restart your pc.
4. Now install your new setup.

Answer (score 0):

From the log, I see these two messages:

> ```
> [09/22/14,12:16:44] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.
> [09/22/14,12:16:44] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: d:\study\software\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs2010 ultimate\vs_setup.msi
> ```

Looks like your installer, or (if using the web installer) one of the downloaded components, is corrupt.

Comment: i'm also felt that, so also tried to install using another setup, but still same problem

Comment: Did you try again with a completely fresh download?